How to get the physical address of a file in RAM?
I have found a couple of related posts:
How to see information inside inode data structure
Is it possible to find the physical address of a file in disk?
But nothing quite answers my question. I have a process which continuously reads a file and I would like to get the physical address of the file it is continuously reading. I know which file it is reading. The process in question does not use mmap.
How can I get the physical address of that file? I presume I can get its address in RAM.
Preferably, if possible, using cmd line utilities instead of having to write a C app.
The process in question:
int main(void)
{
    int iFd = open("/some/path/file.txt",O_RDWR);
    if (iFd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }


    while(1)
    {
        uint8_t tmp[10]={0};
        read(iFd, tmp, sizeof tmp);
        (void) tmp;
    }

    close(iFd);

    return 0;
}

I looked at /proc but the file does not appear there:
# cat /proc/<PID of process>/maps
555fa58000-555fa59000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 34817                          /some/path/myProcess
555fa68000-555fa69000 r--p 00000000 b3:02 34817                          /some/path/myProcess
555fa69000-555fa6a000 rw-p 00001000 b3:02 34817                          /some/path/myProcess
7fb3970000-7fb3ac3000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 786                            /lib/libc-2.31.so
7fb3ac3000-7fb3ad3000 ---p 00153000 b3:02 786                            /lib/libc-2.31.so
7fb3ad3000-7fb3ad6000 r--p 00153000 b3:02 786                            /lib/libc-2.31.so
7fb3ad6000-7fb3ad9000 rw-p 00156000 b3:02 786                            /lib/libc-2.31.so
7fb3ad9000-7fb3adc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fb3adc000-7fb3afd000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 778                            /lib/ld-2.31.so
7fb3b04000-7fb3b06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fb3b0a000-7fb3b0b000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                              [vvar]
7fb3b0b000-7fb3b0c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                              [vdso]
7fb3b0c000-7fb3b0d000 r--p 00020000 b3:02 778                            /lib/ld-2.31.so
7fb3b0d000-7fb3b0f000 rw-p 00021000 b3:02 778                            /lib/ld-2.31.so
7ff5eb9000-7ff5eda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                              [stack]


so, mm, do you mean you want the address of the memory buffer (tmp) the program uses to read the file data into? Are you sure you want the location of that buffer in physical memory, and not the virtual memory address as the process itself sees it? What exactly are you planning to do with the memory address?

A file doesn't have an address. With mmap, the content of the file has a virtual address inside the process, but not when the file is just opened. What information are you actually after? What problem do you want to solve?

This sounds like might be a XY problem. Can you explain which problem you need to solve.

@ilkkachu see context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79107687/how-to-get-the-physical-address-of-a-file-in-ram?noredirect=1#comment139489740_79107687

Like your original question, this question lacks clarity.  You don't explain what you are trying to do, and you have some misconceptions about how these things work.

@traducerad, I would say the fact that your linked question was closed for lacking details and clarity makes it rather a bad reference for providing context for this (more or less?) identical one.

You have not yet added a single point to your question explaining why you need the physical address or why you think a physical address would even be meaningful.

The directory /proc/[pid]/maps is unrelated to open files. It has information on "Memory maps to executables and library files", presumably opened by Linux, not userspace programs.

Physical address in ram is irrelevant to anything except the kernel and the physical ram.   Unless you are running a logic probe against the motherboard, or trying to diagnose bad ram or something like that, the physical address is irrelevant and not useful for anything.  There is no user space API that would let you access physical memory or use the physical address.  The kernel use to have a (very traditional) device to access physical memory, but that was removed long ago as a security risk and not of much use.
The other exception to this would be if you are running in the kernel, in which case there are kernel APIs to get this information.
Without mmap, if the file is in physical memory at all, it is there only ephemerally and those pages could be released at any moment.  Any possible use of the physical address outside of the kernel would be a race condition.
The whole point of mmap is to assign a virtual address to parts of the file.  Just because you have mmaped a file still does not mean it has a physical address or that any part of the file is in memory.  Only when you try to access that virtual memory does it get physically loaded into memory, and even then it would still be ephemeral.  (Note that virtual addresses only have local meaning within the context of a single process.)
It would make more sense to ask how to determine what disk blocks a file is using.  And then maybe it would be interesting to ask what memory is caching those blocks, but it would still be ephemeral and not of much use.
